# Fourier transform of $f(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x)e^{-\lvert x \rvert}$ using $f^{\prime\prime} - f = 2\delta^\prime$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

> Compute the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{f}\left(\,{x}\,\right) = \operatorname{sgn}\left(\,{x}\,\right){\rm e}^{-\left\vert\,{x}\,\right\vert}\ $ ( considered as a tempered distribution ) using that $\operatorname{f}'' - \operatorname{f} = 2\delta'$, where $\delta$ is the $Dirac\ Function$.

Could you please explain to me how to use the ODE $\ \operatorname{f}'' - \operatorname{f} = 2\delta'$ for computing the Fourier transform, I do not understand how to connect these two things here.

Comment: Take the Fourier transform of both sides of that ode

Comment: I think your ODE should read $f^{\prime\prime} - f = 2\delta^\prime$.

Comment: \begin{align*}
\operatorname{f}'\left(\,{x}\,\right) & = 2\delta\left(\,{x}\,\right) - {\rm e}^{-\left\vert\,{x}\,\right\vert}
\\
\operatorname{f}''\left(\,{x}\,\right) & =
2\delta'\left(\,{x}\,\right) + \operatorname{sgn}\left(\,{x}\,\right){\rm e}^{-\left\vert\,{x}\,\right\vert}
\\
\operatorname{f}''\left(\,{x}\,\right) - \operatorname{f}'\left(\,{x}\,\right)& =
2\delta'\left(\,{x}\,\right) - 2\delta\left(\,{x}\,\right) + 2\operatorname{H}\left(\,{x}\,\right){\rm e}^{-\left\vert\,{x}\,\right\vert}
\end{align*}
$\displaystyle\operatorname{H}:\ Heaviside\ Step\ Function$.

Comment: @Felix Martin Thanks. From the second line of your computations, we see the equation indeed is $f''-f=2\delta$.

Comment: @Gateauaufromage: Yeah, you are right the ODE should be $f^{\prime\prime} -f = 2 \delta^\prime$. I corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Ninad Munshi is saying, take the Fourier transform of the equation to get
$$
{\mathscr{F}}\!\left(f''-f\right)\!(\omega)=2{\mathscr{F}}\!\left(\delta'\right)\!(\omega).
$$
Use the fact that the Fourier transform of a derivative of a function is $2\pi i \omega$ times the Fourier transform of the function to get
$$
-(1+4\pi^2\omega^2) \hat{f}(\omega)=4\pi i \omega {\mathscr{F}}\!\left(\delta(x)\right)\!(\omega)=4\pi i \omega,
$$
where we used the fact that the Fourier transform of the Dirac Delta function is equal to 1. Thus
$$
\hat{f}(\omega)=-\frac{4\pi i \omega}{1+4\pi^2\omega^2}.
$$